# Google Spreadsheet Programming, trouble with setValues

Tags: google-apps-script

So I have been trying to do the following in google spreadsheets. 
[The Objective](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BOHnV.png)

I need to go through the numbers in column E and F, find out which of the numbers are greater than its average, and copy the corresponding values from column A, B, and E to column H,I, and J.

If you see the attached picture, I managed to accomplish it using the code I have given below, but the only problem was cells H4:K7, were filled with "NOT_FOUND" when I executed the code. I got this picture by deleting those the three rows.

Here is the code,

```
    function myFunction() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(),sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1"), percentages=sheet.getRange("E3:E78").getValues(),ave,row,len,names=sheet.getRange("A3:A78").getValues(),prices=sheet.getRange("B3:B78").getValues();
   var sum=0,count=0,count1;
   var locs,rowind,colind;
   var result=new Array();
   for (row=0;row<3;row++)
     {
       result[row]=new Array(3);
     }
   for (row=0,len=percentages.length;row<len;row++)
     {
       sum=sum+Number(percentages[row]);
     }
   ave=sum/len;

   for (row=0,len=percentages.length;row<len;row++)
    {
       if (percentages[row]>ave)
         {
            result.push([[names[row]],[prices[row]],[percentages[row]]]);
            count=count+1;
         }
     }

  count=count+3;
  locs=sheet.getRange("H4");
  rowind=locs.getRowIndex();
  colind=locs.getColumn();
  locs=sheet.getRange(rowind,colind,count,3);
  locs.setValues(result); 
  }
```

So I came up with something like this for the code, which resulted in the correct output but an extra 3x3 values of NOT_FOUND.

Prior to using setValues, I tried to return the 2D array 'result', to the spreadsheet, but the spreadsheet refused to get updated through that method.

So that's about it. Any help anyone can provide will be much appreciated :).

Answer (score 0):

Its because after creating the variable "result" you are doing a for loop where you add an array with 3 values in the first 3 rows of the array:

```
var result=new Array();
for (row=0;row<3;row++)
{
  result[row]=new Array(3);
}
```

And after adding those arrays, you are adding the actual results. 
so you end up with three rows with three empty values and then your actual results.
The solution should be to delete that loop.
Let me know if after that you still get the "NOT_FOUND" values.